# Issue when wrapping socket with Observables - MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io, rxjs

I have a **socket.io** server where I have defined a simple class named `SocketObs` to wrap a socket with an Observable.

The code is the following

```
class SocketObs {
    constructor(private socket: any) {}
    onEvent(event): Observable<any> {
        return new Observable<any>((observer: Observer<any>) => {
            this.socket.on(event, data => observer.next(data));
        });
    }
}
```

The server itself is implemented by the class `MyServer`, whose code is this

```
export class MyServer {
    public static readonly PORT = 8081;

    private app: express.Application;
    private server: Server;
    private io: socketIo.Server;
    private port: string | number;

    private observables = new Array<any>();

    constructor() {
        this.app = express();
        this.port = process.env.PORT || MobileObjectServer.PORT;
        this.server = createServer(this.app);
        this.io = socketIo(this.server);
        this.listen();

        for(let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            this.observables.push(from([1, 2, 3]))
        }
    }

    private listen() {
        this.server.listen(this.port, () => {
            console.log('Running server STRESS on port %s', this.port);
        });

        this.io.on('connect', socket => {
            console.log('Connected client on port %s.', this.port);
            const socketObs = new SocketObs(socket);
            socketObs.onEvent('monitor')
            .subscribe(
                () => this.monitoSubscribeToObservables(socketObs)
            )
        });
    }

    private monitoSubscribeToObservables(socket: SocketObs) {
        this.observables.forEach(obs => {
            obs
            .pipe(takeUntil(socket.onEvent('disconnect')))
            .subscribe(null, null, () => console.log('observable completed'));
        })
    }

    public getApp(): express.Application {
        return this.app;
    }

}
```

The logic is very simple

- when the server is created it fills an Array with 20 Observables
- it sets to listening mode and waits until a 'monitor' message arrives
- when the 'monitor' message arrives, it subscribes to the Observables
  created at start time
- the Observable subscriptions are completed when the socket is
  disconnected (yes, I know that this is not really the case, but I
  need to have the `takeUntil` operator for my case to happen)

If I run the server in node, I get the logic executed but then I get the following warning

```
(node:76408) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 disconnect listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
```

If I do the exact same thing but without using the , i.e. with this implementation

```
 private listen() {
        this.server.listen(this.port, () => {
            console.log('Running server STRESS on port %s', this.port);
        });

        this.io.on('connect', socket => {
            console.log('Connected client on port %s.', this.port);

            socket.on('monitor', () => {
                this.monitoSubscribeToObservables(socket);
            });

        });
    }

    private monitoSubscribeToObservables(socket: socketIo.Socket) {
        const monitorDisconnected = new Subject<any>();
        this.observables.forEach(obs => {
            obs
            .pipe(takeUntil(monitorDisconnected))
            .subscribe(null, null, () => console.log('observable completed'));
        })
        socket.on('disconnect', () => {
            console.log('Monitor disconnected');
            monitorDisconnected.next();
        });
    }
```

the warning is not raised any more.

I am struggling to understand the reason of this different behavior.